# CDT uses too much memory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an [AUTOSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOSAR) project(1.1k sources) which I want to index using the `C/C++ Indexer` plugin on `eclipse oxygen(4.7.3)`. After I got an `Out of heap space error` with `-xmx4g` I wanted to see how much memory it really needs so I configured `-xmx10g`, yet it wasn't enough.

Taking a snapshot with `jvisualvm.exe` from `JDK 1.8` I see 7 gb of `char[]` objects kept in memory.

After about 10 minutes of running, the indexing didn't pass the first file from the 1.1k files to analyze.

What do I have to do to get a fix on such a problem? 
Or where should I look to find the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get such a problem fixed is to reduce your project to a minimal set of files that reproduce the problem, and then [file a CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) with the files attached.

The reduction can be done using binary search: delete half the files in your project, and see if the problem persists. If so, delete half of the remaining files, and so on. (It helps to consider dependency order when choosing which files to delete, i.e. avoid deleting a file before deleting files that depend on it.) When you only have a few files left, you can perform the binary search on their contents. Ideally you arrive at a minimal reproducing testcase of maybe 100-200 lines spread out over 1-3 files, at which point you can rename identifiers to be generic and post the code.

I would suggest testing with the latest release (CDT 9.5.2) before doing this, to make sure you're not running into an issue that has already been fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that with the latest CDT

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, -xmx is accepted .. or is it rather -Xmx.
I usually use the following in eclipse.ini:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
```

1.1k Sources doesn't sound much (we have much more), but on the other side, some generated files can eat up a lot of memory and performance, e.g. Rte.c and Rte_*.h files (e.g. Rte.c here is about 100k LOC). Together with CDTs features of AST based syntax and semantic highlighting eats up memory and also performance.

Comment: The settings work fine, I can see the memory consumption from `Task Manager`. The projects also make use of `Rte` generated files, but more than that we face include files with circular dependencies and also files without guarding ( I assume some inifinite loop occurs).